# Function to show the lowest represented element in a list

Tags: haskell

If you have a list such as this in Haskell:

```
data TestType = A | B | C deriving (Ord, Eq, Show) 

List1 :: [TestType]
List1 = [A,B,C,B,C,A,B,C,C,C]
```

Is it possible to write a function to determin which element is represented the least in a list (so in this case 'A')

My initial thought was to write a helper function such as this but now I am not sure if this is the right approach:

```
appears :: TestType -> [TestType] -> Int
appears _ [] = 0
appears x (y:ys) | x==y = 1 + (appears x ys)
                 | otherwise = appears x ys
```

I am still fairly new to Haskell, so apologies for the potentially silly question.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly alternative version to Matt's approach

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

leastFrequent :: Ord a => [a] -> a
leastFrequent = head . minimumBy (comparing length) . group . sort
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a prettier way to do it.  Nice!

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I am after!

Comment: much more pretty and shortly than mine +1

Comment: An element that is not in the list at all occurs 0 times, which is less than 1.  This solution does not account for that.

Comment: @augustss true but that doesnt really fit in my definition of the problem. I am only concerned with what is actually 'in' the list.

Comment: @EdGeorge You didn't really specify if you only wanted elements in the list, or elements from the type in general.  Anyway, it's easy to get the one I suggest by `. (++ [minBound .. maxBound])` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a map counting how often each item occurs in the list

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

frequencies list = Map.fromListWith (+) $ zip list (repeat 1)
```

Then you can find the least/most represented using `minimumBy` or `maximumBy` from `Data.List` on the list of `Map.assocs` of the frequency map, or even sort it by frequency using `sortBy`.

```
module Frequencies where

import Data.Ord
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map as Map

frequencyMap :: Ord a => [a] -> Map.Map a Int
frequencyMap list = Map.fromListWith (+) $ zip list (repeat 1)

-- Caution: leastFrequent will cause an error if called on an empty list!
leastFrequent :: Ord a => [a] -> a
leastFrequent = fst . minimumBy (comparing snd) . Map.assocs . frequencyMap

ascendingFrequencies :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
ascendingFrequencies = sortBy (comparing snd) . Map.assocs . frequencyMap
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

1. sort the list
2. group the list
3. find the length of each group
4. return the group with the shortest length

Example:

```
import GHC.Exts
import Data.List

fewest :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a
fewest xs = fst $ head sortedGroups 
where 
  sortedGroups = sortWith snd $ zip (map head groups) (map length groups)
  groups = group $ sort xs
```

Answer (score 1):

A less elegant idea would be:

- At first sort and group the list
- then pairing the cases with their number of representations
- at last sort them relative to their num of representations

In code this looks like

```
import Data.List                                                                 

sortByRepr :: (Ord a) => [a] ->[(a,Int)]
sortByRepr xx = sortBy compareSnd $ map numOfRepres $ group $ sort xx
              where compareSnd x y = compare (snd x) (snd y)
                    numOfRepres x = (head x, length x)
```

the least you get by applying head to the resulting list.